# Who is "Miyuki-senpai"?

Tags: kiss-him-not-me

When Mutsumi and Serinuma are at the shrine in episode 12, Mutsumi asks Serinuma what she wished for. She replies that she wished:

- for the Lord and Akane to live happily ever after
- for Shion to come back to life
- for Captain Levi to be more *dere*
- for "Miyuki-senpai" to notice [someone]'s true feelings

The first two are from shows-within-the-show "Kachu Rabu" and "Mirage Saga". The third one is *Attack on Titan* (which has been referenced weirdly often). What's the fourth one from?

Comment: for me, a google search for Miyuki-senpai shows a whole bunch of facebook profiles. the only one that isn't is a wikia like to [Miyuki Kazuya](http://diamondnoace.wikia.com/wiki/Miyuki_Kazuya) from [*Ace of Diamond*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_of_Diamond). ofcause it could be Miyuki is no one and like the Levi one is just a nudge at something well know or popular with anime/manga culture, in this case [*"notice me senpai"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=notice%20me%20senpai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Miyuki is from Daiya no A or Ace of Diamond in English.... That "notice me sempai" is tagged on because as an ace catcher, the pitcher (Sawamura) fights kinda for his attention with another pitcher.... There are a lot of Sawamura and Miyuki doujins out there and they are a fan favorite ship.

Answer (score 2):

Miyuki-senpai is from Daiya no Ace. The anime is centered around Sawamura (MC) and Miyuki's relationships as pitcher-catcher (the author said so). Sawamura wants Miyuki to acknowledge him as a capable pitcher, yet his rival on the same team, Furuya, as the ace, made Miyuki pay attention to him more. Sawamura struggled to make the best battery with Miyuki, hence 'notice me senpai'.